# XMLHttpRequest missing body for PATCH in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to call an API using the PATCH http method from IE9, every time the `XMLHttpRequest` is sent it drops the actual request body. The actual request is coming from an AngularJS application. Angular just uses the native xhr under the covers in it's `$http` service.  I've verified the behavior is not Angular-specific running the snippet below in the IE console and inspecting the network traffic - no body gets sent with the request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('PATCH', '/api/v1/fake/404/', false);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
request.send('{"isActive": 1}');
```

if you change PATCH to PUT or POST it sends the json request body just fine. Is PATCH just not supported in IE9 XHR? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

After doing a bunch of research. it appears that there really isn't any workaround. PATCH http requests just aren't supported in IE9.

Comment: This is not accurate.